# Insertion into SQL Server based on condition

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and the table has already data for month of November. I have to insert data for previous months such as starting from Jan through October. I have data in a spreadsheet. I want to do bulk insert using Python. I have successfully established the connection to the server using Python and able to access the table. However, I don't know how to insert data above the rows those are already present in the table of the server. The table doesn't have any constraints, primary keys and index. 
I am not sure whether the insertion is possible based on the condition. If it is possible kindly share some clues.

Notes: I don't have access to SSIS. I can't do insertion using "BULK INSERT" because the I can't map my shared drive with SQL server. That's why I have decided to use python script to do the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is just the GUI for interacting with SQL Server.

> However, I don't know how to insert data above the rows those are
>   already present in the table of the server

Tables are *ordered* or structured based off the [clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017). Since you don't have one since you said there aren't any PK's or indexes, inserting the records "below" or "above" won't happen. A table without a [clustered index is called a HEAP which is what you have.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Thus, just insert the data. The *order* will be determined by any `order by` clauses you place on a statement (at least the order of the results) or the clustered index on the table if you create one.

I assume you think your data is ordered because, by chance, when you run `select * from table` your results appear to be in the same order each time. However, [this blog will show you that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/) this isn't guaranteed and elaborates on the fact that your results truly aren't ordered without an `order by` clause.

Comment: I say more. Ever you have PK or index, it does not matter in which order you insert data. You always can chose order (by date or some other field) on select.